# How to deploy an AWS Amplify app from GitHub Actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-amplify, github-actions

I want to control Amplify deployments from GitHub Actions because Amplify auto-build

- doesn't provide a GitHub Environment
- doesn't watch the CI for failures and will deploy anyways, or
- requires me to duplicate the CI setup and re-run it in Amplify
- didn't support running a `cypress` job out-of-the-box

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Turn off auto-build (in the `App settings / General / Branches`).
- Add the following script and job

`scripts/amplify-deploy.sh`

```sh
echo "Deploy app $1 branch $2"
JOB_ID=$(aws amplify start-job --app-id $1 --branch-name $2 --job-type RELEASE | jq -r '.jobSummary.jobId')
echo "Release started"
echo "Job ID is $JOB_ID"

while [[ "$(aws amplify get-job --app-id $1 --branch-name $2 --job-id $JOB_ID | jq -r '.job.summary.status')" =~ ^(PENDING|RUNNING)$ ]]; do sleep 1; done
JOB_STATUS="$(aws amplify get-job --app-id $1 --branch-name $2 --job-id $JOB_ID | jq -r '.job.summary.status')"
echo "Job finished"
echo "Job status is $JOB_STATUS"
```

```
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
      AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT: json
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Deploy
      run: ./scripts/amplify-deploy.sh xxxxxxxxxxxxx master
```

You could improve the script to fail if the release fails, add needed steps (e.g. lint, test), add a GitHub Environment, etc.

There's also [`amplify-cli-action`](https://github.com/ambientlight/amplify-cli-action) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: with this approach, did you get the actual build logs in Github Action? or you will still need to go to amplify console to see the details if anything fails?

Comment: @thisismydesign Is it possible if you can share the whole pipeline code here. I have the same questions to run cypress, deploy to aws amplify and i have multiple packages i am using lerna .

Comment: Doesn’t this just kick off a build and deploy in Amplify? Is there no way to deploy directly without using the Amplify pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to answer 2 here, but I used tags instead.

Create an action like ci.yml, turn off auto-build on the staging & prod envs in amplify and create the webhook triggers.

```
name: CI-Staging
on:
  release:
    types: [prereleased]
permissions: read-all # This is required to read the secrets
jobs:
  deploy-staging:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: read-all # This is required to read the secrets
    steps:
      - name: deploy
        run: |
          URL="${{ secrets.STAGING_DEPLOY_WEBHOOK }}"
          curl -X POST -d {} "$URL" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

name: CI-production
on:
  release:
    types: [released]
permissions: read-all # This is required to read the secrets
jobs:
  deploy-production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: read-all # This is required to read the secrets
    steps:
      - name: deploy
        run: |
          URL="${{ secrets.PRODUCTION_DEPLOY_WEBHOOK }}"
          curl -X POST -d {} "$URL" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this answer a little bit? How do the tags work?
I want to set up a series of actions in github so that unit tests run, then ui tests run, and only if those both pass, fire off the build for the correct environment in amplify.

Answer (score 3):

1. Disable automatic builds:

- Go to `App settings > general` in the AWS Amplify console and disable automatic builds there.

2. Go to `App settings > Build Settings` and create a web hook which is a `curl` command that will trigger a build.

- Example: `curl -X POST -d {} URL -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

3. Save the URL in GitHub as a secret.
4. Add the `curl` script to the GitHub actions YAML script like this:

```
deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - name: deploy
    run: |
        URL="${{ secrets.WEBHOOK_URL }}"
        curl -X POST -d {} "$URL" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```