# AWS Amplify GitHub action in specific folder

Tags: github-actions, aws-amplify

I do not like the automatic deployment AWS Amplify provides with your git repo so I am making my own GitHub action for it. Using [How to deploy an AWS Amplify app from GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354484/how-to-deploy-an-aws-amplify-app-from-github-actions) as my inspiration, I have a semi complete action that looks like:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          URL="${{ secrets.AMPLIFY_WEBHOOK_URL }}"
          curl -X POST -d {} "$URL" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

However, my road-blocker is my repo is monolithic repo and my frontend application that I want on Amplify is located in a specific folder. My repo structure looks like:

```
root/
  frontend/
```

Since I only want the contents of frontend to be sent within this curl command, I'm assuming some sort of `cd frontend` will have to be performed before I make the curl command? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the frontend folder on amplify allows the suggestions in the linked post to work fine. Once the code is deployed to amplify it will know what the frontend folder is based on what you told it.